# convergence of normal sum r.v. tail

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(Z_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d standard normal r.v.'s. I am trying to evaluate the limit 
$$\lim_n \frac{\log P(Z_1+...+Z_n>n) }{ n}.$$
The limit evaluates to -1/2 using some very strange order expansions (wolfram alpha). I am looking for a simpler way to solve this.

Comment: Do you mean $X_n = Z_n$?

Comment: Check out the "Mills ratio".

Comment: There are two different Mills ratios, I dont see how either of them apply here? the Log only applies to the numerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum $S_n=Z_1+Z_2+\ldots+Z_n$ is distributed as $N(0,n)$, so $P(S_n>n)=Q(\sqrt n)$ where $Q$ is the upper tail cdf of the normal, $Q(x)=1-\Phi(x)$ in the usual notation.  It is a well-known [fact](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.8) about the gaussian [Mill's ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio) $Q(x)/\phi(x)$ that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xQ(x)}{\phi(x)} = 1,$$ 
where $\phi(x)$ is the density function for the standard normal. Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log\left(\sqrt n Q(\sqrt n)/ \phi(\sqrt n)\right) = 0$$

and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{\log n}2 +\log Q(\sqrt n) +\frac{\log(2\pi)}2+n/2\right) = 0 .$$
This implies $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log Q(\sqrt n)} n = -\frac 1 2$.